# Knockout 3.4 and above fail with iOS 11 to embed <video> tag

Tags: knockout.js, safari

I use Knockout templates to dynamically build up a page containing a number of **inline** video clips.

I noticed recently that iOS11 was acting very quirkily and not playing videos well.

The video would appear as it if was starting to play - the progress bar would even move - but the video didn't play. Interestingly clicking the 'full screen icon' would trigger it to start playing in full screen and it would continue playing fine inline when the full screen mode is closed.

After stripping the site completely down it seems that my use of Knockout templates with the video tag was causing the issue. Reverting to Knockout version 3.3.0 restored flawless operation. This is the version of Knockout that introduced microtasks and I'm guessing the issue maybe has something to do with a weird timing problem.

This is the simplest version that fails:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>The following video is dynamically inserted from a Knockout template</h1>
    <h1>This version is Knockout 3.4.0</h1>
    <!-- ko template: { name: 'videoTemplate' } --><!-- /ko -->

    <template id="videoTemplate">

        <video muted playsinline preload="auto" controls
               width="500" height="300">

            <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>

    </template>

    <script>
        setTimeout(function ()
        {
            ko.applyBindings();
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Knockout 3.4.0 version (doesn't work on iOS11)**

https://embed.plnkr.co/L05w8x1iVBbauibG7yev?show=preview

**Knockout 3.3.0 version (OK)**

https://embed.plnkr.co/EpPkzCdq2zgNIRYO8eYU?show=preview

How I can fix or work around this?

I don't know if I need to disable microtasks, generate the video tag from scratch, or reassign the source dynamically after the template is created. Trying to Google for iOS video bugs brings up mostly ancient stuff.

I believe Safari on Mac also has this problem but I only have access to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that reverting back to

```
<script type="text/html" id="videoTemplate">
```

as opposed to

```
<template id="videoTemplate">
```

Fixed the issue.

Must be some kind of pre-parsing that Safari does with the template. By making it `<script>` it doesn't look inside at the contents so it can't get confused.

Comment: Also reported here https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2344#issuecomment-362952135